# Facebook graph api can't get email

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to integrate facebook login into my webapp, and I want to get the email from the user, but I can only get the ID and name all the time, please give me some tips if you know how to fixed it.

***index.jsp***

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%@page import="java.net.URLEncoder" %>
<%
    String fbURL = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=facebookAppID&redirect_uri=" + URLEncoder.encode("http://localhost:8080/TestFacebook/signin_fb.do?")+"&scope=email";
%>

<a href="<%= fbURL %>"><img src="img/facebookloginbutton.png" border="0" /></a>
</body>
</html>
```

***Servlet***

```
package login;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


@WebServlet("/signin_fb.do")
public class SignInFB extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String code = req.getParameter("code");
        if (code == null || code.equals("")) {
            // an error occurred, handle this
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "ERROR: Didn't get code parameter in callback.");
        }

        String token = null;
        try {
            String g = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=facebookAppID&redirect_uri=" + URLEncoder.encode("http://localhost:8080/TestFacebook/signin_fb.do", "UTF-8") + "&client_secret=AppSecret&code=" + code;
            URL u = new URL(g);
            URLConnection c = u.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                b.append(inputLine + "\n");            
            in.close();
            token = b.toString();
            System.out.println("token= "+token);
            if (token.startsWith("{"))
                throw new Exception("error on requesting token: " + token + " with code: " + code);
        } catch (Exception e) {
                // an error occurred, handle this
            throw new RuntimeException("ERROR: Access Token Invalid: "
                    + token);
        }

        String graph = null;
        try {
            String g = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?"+token;
            URL u = new URL(g);
            URLConnection c = u.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                b.append(inputLine + "\n");            
            in.close();
            graph = b.toString();
            System.out.println("graph= " +graph);
        } catch (Exception e) {
                // an error occurred, handle this
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("ERROR in getting FB graph data. " + e);
        }

        String facebookId;
        String firstName;
        String middleNames;
        String lastName;
        String email;

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(graph);
            facebookId = json.getString("id");
            firstName = json.getString("first_name");
            lastName = json.getString("last_name");
            email = json.getString("email");
            ServletOutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();
            out.print("<div>Welcome "+firstName+" "+lastName);
            out.print("<div>Email: "+email);
            System.out.println("json= "+json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // an error occurred, handle this
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(req, resp);
    }

}
```

I want to print out the status of user, but the only thing I get is
graph= {"name":"XXX","id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}, Please let me know if you have any way to fix it, appreciate for any help.

Comment: you are not asking for the email in the api call, so you don´t get it. there are many stackoverflow threads about this already, please do some research before asking.

Comment: the duplicate thread is about the JS SDK, but it´s the same issue

Comment: I have seen this before, but when I try to add "&fields=email" of "&scope=email" after 'String g = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?"+token;' it shows me that Illegal character in URL, So where should I should I ask specific? Thanks for reply.

Comment: I think I found the problem, it can't find my firstname and lastname in Chinese form so keeps throw out Exception. Thanks a lot!